# saving time to mongodb with golang with api, but the time is not matched

Tags: mongodb, go

this is my struct located in different go file

```
type ImageData struct {
    Id   primitive.ObjectID `json:"id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Time time.Time  `json:"time,omitempty" bson:"time,omitempty"`
    Path    string  `json:"path,omitempty" bson:"path,omitempty"`
    SizeBefore  string  `json:"sizebefore,omitempty" bson:"sizebefore,omitempty"`
    SizeAfter   string  `json:"sizeafter,omitempty" bson:"sizeafter,omitempty"`
    IsSuccess   bool    `json:"issuccess,omitempty" bson:"issuccess,omitempty"`
}
```

this is create function located in different go file

```
func CreateImageData(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    var image models.ImageData

    json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&image)
    image.Time = time.Now()

    collection := database.ImageData()
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    result, _ := collection.InsertOne(ctx, image)

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(result)
}
```

when i create a ImageData struct and save to database the time isnt match
this is data in my mongodb

```
[
    {
        "id": "6453e3a9b680e192e2fb82aa",
        "time": "2023-05-04T16:56:09.67Z",
        "path": "/result/test1.png",
        "sizebefore": "785KB",
        "sizeafter": "785KB"
    }
]
```

but my real time is 2023-05-04T23:57:00

how to fix this to make the time accurate

sorry for bad english

Comment: I guess your real time is `2023-05-04T23:57:00+07:00` instead. Please note that `2023-05-04T16:56:09.67Z` is a UTC time. If your timezone is +07:00, then that UTC time is `2023-05-04 23:56:09.67` in your timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'time' package and the 'Format' function to convert the datetime into a valid format.

Please note that you need to change the format of the datetime as MongoDB uses UTC format.

Here's an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    now := time.Now().UTC()
    formatted := now.Format(time.RFC3339Nano)
    fmt.Println(formatted)
}
```

Comment: still doesnt work for me when i saved to database but when i print out the time is correct

Comment: You need change de timezone of your mongoDB to coincide with your timezone.

In this [article](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-change-the-data-timezone-in-mongodb-atlas/169488) explain how change the timezone in mongoDB Atlas.

You can see your time zone with this commands:
- Ubuntu: `timedatectl`
- Mac: `sudo systemsetup -gettimezone`
- Windows: `systeminfo | findstr  /C:"Time Zone"`